Ｗhy is のか used in this sentence?

The character says "this place feels nostalgic"
But then "I came to here to drink?" why is he not sure of it?

The provided context is not sufficient, but the implied subject is almost certainly not "I". A likely translation would be "So you guys (usually) drink at places like this!", "So this kind of place is where she always drinks, huh?", or something similar.
Also, I wonder how you saw the meaning of "came to here". で ("at") is a location marker, not a destination marker. 飲んでんのか is short for 飲んでいるのか, where:

ている indicates a habitual action
の is a plain explanatory-no
か is for discovery (the same か as in そうか = "I got it!")

